# Asp.net 5 middleware feature as a modular application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As we can see middleware can produce rotes `app.UseRuntimeInfoPage(); // default path is /runtimeinfo`

I wish create a CRUD module with their js and css and cshtml files using asp.net 5 middleware feature.

```
app.UseCustumerModule(); // produce /custumer, /custumer/new , /custumer/delete 
app.UseProductModule(); // produce /product, /product/new , /product/delete 
app.UseSalesModule();
```

or better:

```
app.UseMiddleware<CustumerModule>();
app.UseMiddleware("ProductAssemblyName");
```

In source code we have https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/RuntimeInfoPageOptions.cs#L18 and then https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/RuntimeInfoExtensions.cs

Comment: Do you have any result for now?

Comment: not yet, may be I post it at git hub

Comment: Were you able to implement this? Can you point me to the location on GitHub? Thanks!

Comment: Not yeat, it's just a proposal for ASP.net 5 team at github and you can see discussion at https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2845 and https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/973 but if you look something in asp.net 4, you could get some insights at http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/How+to+write+a+nopCommerce+plugin and http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx